# How can I change Surefire Test Case name programatically using TestNG?

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have been experimenting a problem with Surefire.

I don't know how to change the name of the Test Suite and the name of the Test Case programatically.

Now I have this test suite and this test case name:

```
INFO: Starting the test suite: [Surefire suite] ... 
INFO: Starting the test case: [Surefire test] ...
```

How can I change `Surefire suite` and `Surefire test` into the TestNG test name and test suite? Do I have to edit the pom.xml file?

Comment: How are you running the tests from surefire? invoking xml or direct test?

Comment: I do it in different ways. XML, directly or via maven

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately this is not possible:
https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/surefire-providers/surefire-testng/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/surefire/testng/TestNGExecutor.java#L63

Comment: Please add some content from the links.

Comment: In code:
`/** The default name for a suite launched from the maven surefire plugin */
public static final String DEFAULT_SUREFIRE_SUITE_NAME = "Surefire suite";
/** The default name for a test launched from the maven surefire plugin */
public static final String DEFAULT_SUREFIRE_TEST_NAME = "Surefire test";

private static class TestMetadata
{
    private String testName = DEFAULT_SUREFIRE_TEST_NAME;
    private String suiteName = DEFAULT_SUREFIRE_SUITE_NAME;
}
// and further testName and suiteName not changed.`

Comment: Or make changes to the library surefire-testng, to DEFAULT_SUREFIRE_SUITE_NAME DEFAULT_SUREFIRE_TEST_NAME and could set the example from the command line. Built and install a modified library. As I did for myself.